# Python datetime loses timezone awareness after mysql insert and select

Tags: python, datetime

I have a block of code that stores time/date that a report was run to a mysql data base so that later i can later read it back and make sure it is at least 2 hours before I run the report request again.  The problem is I lose time zone awareness when saving to mysql and back.   For example when I try to calc the deltatime from the current time to last_run time I get back error 'TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes.'  This makes sense but I don't know how to fix.  All the times are actually UTC so I dont have a timezone difference.  1)Can I convert the datetime.now(timezone.utc) in to a non-aware date?  2)When I save the last_run time in to mysql can I preserve the timezone awareness?

**Code that does subtraction That Errors**

```
time_since_last_request = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - last_run
```

**Code that Sets 'last_run' in the database**

```
current_time=datetime.now(timezone.utc)
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_rpt_log SET last_run=%s, report_id=%s where user=%s", (current_time, ReportID, ,user))
db.commit()
```

**Code that reads back the last_run time right before the subtraction that fails**

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_rpt_log")
reports_to_run = cursor.fetchall()  

for row in reports_to_run :
  last_run=(row[4])
  time_since_last_request = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - last_run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable is timezone-aware:

```
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

whereas this is not:

```
last_run = (row[4])
```

In which case, you can add timezone information to the latter using

```
last_run = row[4].astimezone(timezone.utc)
last_run = row[4].replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)  # if db is already in UTC
```

The complete example becomes

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_rpt_log")
reports_to_run = cursor.fetchall()  

for row in reports_to_run :
  last_run = row[4].astimezone(timezone.utc)
  time_since_last_request = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - last_run
```

Comment: I thought this was going to be it as it makes sense.  It is currently 5:11 UTC.    When I print last_run without .astimezone(timezone.utc) it prints as 5:11.  However when add the comment you suggested it pushes the time forward to 9:11 UTC which has not happened yet.   So it looks like the command you suggested pushes UTC time ahead 4 hours which is the differnce I am from UTC. 

INFO:__main__:Last_run  : 2018-08-15 05:11:02
INFO:__main__:Last_run  ast : 2018-08-15 09:11:02+00:00